# How to eager load different nested relationships of polymorphic relationships?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, relationship

I'm trying to get all the Reviews of a User, with their Event.
I have a polymorphic relationship in Review: it can be linked to either an Estimate or an EventDate.
EventDate is directly linked to Event, but Estimate is linked to it through AskEstimate.

I'd like to do this :

```
User::with([
   'reviews.reviewable.event',
   'reviews.reviewable.ask_estimate.event'
])->get();
```

But of course it throws an exception: when reviewable is an EventDate, it doesn't have any AskEstimate relation and when it is an Estimate, it doesn't have any Event relation.

So how can I get something giving me either one or the other, according to the reviewable value?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is a working version.

```
Review::where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->with([
                'reviewable',
                ])
            ->loadMorph('reviewable', [
                Estimate::class => ['ask_estimate'],
                EventDate::class => ['event'],
            ]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Delena for your answer.

According to [the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), I think that loadMorph must be used like that :

```
User::with('reviews.reviewable')
            ->limit(1)
            ->get()
            ->loadMorph('reviews.reviewable', [
                Estimate::class => ['ask_estimate.event'],
                EventDate::class => ['event'],
            ]);
```

But with this one I'm only getting the result of `reviews.reviewable`, I'm not getting any event or ask_estimate, like if loadMorph was useless.

Comment: Didn't know this method was added

Answer (score 1):

The [Nested Lazy Eager Loading & `morphTo`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) section in the docs seems to describe almost exactly what you're looking for. It does "lazy" eager loading instead of eager loading, but I guess that's close enough.

From how I understand the docs you should be able to use the `loadMorph` method like this:

```
User::with('reviews')->get()
   ->loadMorph('reviews', [
       Estimate::class => ['event'],
       EventDate::class => ['ask_estimate.event'],
    ]);
```